# Calculate Differences based on Date in R

Tags: r

So I'm working on looking at people's financial outcomes after counseling. The dataframe "counseling" looks like this, note that a person will have multiple sessions with different scores logged every session:

```
           Name      Date        credit score
            A       1/7/2016        600
            A       1/28/2016       620  
            C       2/2/2016        700 
            C       3/2/2016        660
            C       4/4/2016        750
```

I want to write a function that takes the data frame sorted on two levels (already did that) and then takes the last and first entry for the name and finds the difference in credit score. I am looking to establish the change in credit score that clients get from participating in this counseling service from the time they enter to the time they leave because I want to then output these into a vector and calculate the mean. I'm not quite sure how to tell R to distinguish between the last and first entry for every name. Not sure how to approach this. Greatly appreciate the help guys!

Comment: Use the `head` and `tail` function in R.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tapply` to apply a function to each `Name` group (assuming you've sorted your data first, which you said you had):

```
with(dat, tapply(creditscore, Name, FUN=function(x) tail(x,1) - head(x,1)) )
# A  C 
#20 50
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this using `data.table` (useful if data are large, and sorting is not necessary):

```
library(data.table)

dat$Date <- as.Date(dat$Date,format="%m/%d/%Y")
setDT(dat)

res <- dat[,creditscore[which(Date==max(Date))]-creditscore[which(Date==min(Date))], by = Name]

> res
   Name V1
1:    A 20
2:    C 50
```

Based om some discussions on efficiency with @Frank, here is a more 'data.table'-way that orders the data once, and then uses indexing to calculate our results:

```
res <- dat[order(creditscore),creditscore[.N]-creditscore[1], by = Name]
```

Comment: True. It's a personal preference, I don't like to depend on positions in datasets.

Comment: @Heroka Amen - impossible to debug later.

Comment: More nuanced: I don't like to trust in sorted positions in data, unless I've just put things somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution (sorting with the arrange line just for safety):

```
df %>%
group_by(Name) %>%
arrange(Date) %>%
summarise(last(creditscore)-first(creditscore))
```

Answer (score 0):

If your dataframe is called df -

```
CreditSc<-data.frame()
j<-1
for (i in unique(df$Name))
{
subs<-subset(df, Name == i)
CreditSc[j,]<-tail(subs$CreditScore, n = 1) - head(subs$CreditScore, n = 1)
j<-j+1
}
```

Comment: You probably know already, but growin objects in a loop like this can be very slow when the number of groups is large...

Comment: deleted my comment. My bad.

Comment: No worries. Here to challenge assumptions :)

Comment: your name should be 'heroine'ka ... just saying :P

Comment: Thanks guys, was able to get it going. Used:                 credit_list = with(ffp, tapply(creditscore, name, FUN=function(x) tail(x,1) - head(x,1)))
credit_list = as.data.frame(credit_list) and then found the mean. Going to attempt using some of the other suggestions though, to see what might be more convenient and applicable for larger data frames.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create 2 date variables. We will create two date variables in Date format (YYYY-MM-DD) using the as. Date() function.
2. Difference between two dates. We will use difftime() function to carry out this task.

   ```
   difftime(date1, date2, units = )
   ```